# Assigning values to a large number of variables in php after an if ()

Tags: php

Do you know a better way to do thing when it comes to assigning values to a large number of variables after an if?

In my case it like this:

```
$akeType = array_key_exists('type',$handle);
$akeParent = array_key_exists('parent',$handle);
$akeUserName = array_key_exists('userName',$handle);
$akeUserId = array_key_exists('userId',$handle);
$akeCountryCode = array_key_exists('userId',$handle);

if ( $akeType && $akeParent && $akeUserName && $akeUserId & $akeCountryCode ) {
$listType   = $handle['type'];
$listParent = $handle['parent'];
$listUserName = $handle['userName'];
$listUserId = $handle['userId'];
$foo = $_POST['foo'];
$bar = $_POST['bar'];
$listCountryCode = $handle['countryCode']; // Is there a way to clean up this part? The assignments to variables.
```

Comment: sometimes code is just verbose. and that's ok.

Comment: Do you really need to assign the array variables to new variables, can't you just use the array directly or do something like `$list = $handle`?

Comment: You can produce fewer lines by using a loop and variable variables, but that would not necessarily be better code in this case. I vote for readability over compactness.

Comment: What is the reason for assigning values to a large number of variables? Large numbers are WAY more handy when stored in *arrays*

Comment: @jeroen I need to assign them to new variables. Makes it easier later in the script.

Comment: btw: beware with copy/paste error: `$akeCountryCode = array_key_exists('***userId***',$handle);`

Comment: Then use something like `$list = $handle`; arrays are easier to group and handle information than different variables.

Comment: In what way is `$listUserId` easier to use later on than `$handle['userId']` (or even `$list['userId']`)?? Don't be afraid of using an array -- this is a classic example of where an array is the right answer, not dozens of named variables. An array will make your code easier to work with, and you'll definitely thank youself for using one later, when you need to add a few new fields some time in the future.

Answer (score 3):

take a look at the `extract` -- Import variables into the current symbol table from an array

```
extract($handle, EXTR_OVERWRITE, "ake_");
```

Comment: Answer is not quite correct -- his `$ake..` vars are not being used in this way (they're booleans for whether given keys are set or not). You should have extracted to `"list_"` to match the question. But in any case, I disagree with using `extract()` here, or in most cases; why pull variables into the main symbol table when you've already got them perfectly accessible in the array? Just use the array elements you already have.

Comment: @spudley I for preference would do what you are saying as well, just from a memory utilization standpoint but that's not what the poster was asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the somewhat more obscure code following:

```
$keys= array('type','parent','userName', 'userId');
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $nametoset= "list".ucfirst($key);
    $$nametoset= $handle[$key];
}
```

`$$nametoset` refers to the variable named like the string `$nametoset`. 
Similar code may be used for the `$ake...` variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to set your variable *list*.

For your specific case, you can use the following code:

```
foreach ($handle as $key => $value) {
    $var_name = 'list'.$key;
    $$var_name = $value;
}

foreach ($_POST as $pkey => $pvalue) {
    $$pkey = $pvalue;
}
```

These loops create variables depending on your arrays keys.

Comment: Even though the use of variable variables can seem tempting, this is a nightmare for IDEs and other code checking tools. I personnally try to avoid this technique as much as possible. This comment applies to @Adder's answer too.

Comment: Yes, definitely a bad practice. I should said that on my answer as well... but, it's what the OP is looking for. Thanks for your recommendation anyways.